# JSON post using Python requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, post

I am using python 2.7 on windows 7 with requests requests module.

I am trying to find the source of some data from a website that uses AJAX/javascript to drive events.

Here is my python post:

```
result = s.post(url, headers = {'referer': my_referer})
```

The output from this post looks like this:

```
{"ADATA":{"COUNT":0.0,"AITEM":[]},"WM":0.0,"CM":0.0,"PC":"","PW":"","NC":14,"RR":false,"RTIME":{"RITEM":[],"COUNT":0.0},"WC":1.0,"CC":1.0,"RW":false,"RA":false,"RC":true}
```

`"AITEM":[]` should be populated with all the data I'm after but as you see its not. Also `RC:` should be `false`. Or at least it is when I go through my browser

Note that I get `"RA":true` and `"RC":false` if I use get instead of post request. I dont know why.

Here is the corresponding post in the javascript server side:

```
$.getJSON (url, function(data){UpdateStuff(data);});
```

Disclaimer: I have been programming for about a week now.

This JSON post is in a function that receives no parameters and returns nothing as far as I can tell. `data` is not referenced in the function prior to the post. I dont really understand what `function(data)` is. `UpdateStuff(data)` is another function with a bunch of code that takes `data` and returns nothing. The code reveals some stuff about the data structure with references such as:

```
if (data.RA){resetAL();} else {
if (data.RR ){objAR.attr('ref','Y');}
if (data.RC ){objAC.attr('ref','Y');}
if (data.RW ){objAW.attr('ref','Y');}
```

Which I guess I am failing this logic gate since my data is different than what I see in a successful browser request.

and references to `data.ADATA.COUNT` and `data.ADATA.AITEM[i]` etc

I've been told this would be much simpler to write in JS but I have about 70% of this program done in python already and I've never used JS.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function parameter to `getJSON` is called when the data is returned, so it has nothing to do with what gets sent. Note that `getJSON` means it is a GET, not a POST, though.

Comment: I see. Does that mean the output of `getJSON` is stored in data and then passed to `UpdateStuff(data)`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, while it is getJSON there is in fact data being sent to the server with the url. `function(data){UpdateStuff(data);}` is being sent as the getJSON data parameter

Comment: No, not at all. If there was data, it would be passed as an object parameter in the second place. The function is called with the *result* that comes back from the server.

Comment: I changed the parameters of my request to include cookies and removed the referer as such: `s.post(url, data = cookies)` and its working for now. Thanks for your input Daniel